How can I shape tangzhong dough?
I've recently been playing with using tangzhong (湯種) to make my mantou softer and to get them to keep longer.  Before, they had a tendency to be hard by the time the day was over; once I started using the tangzhong though, not only were they softer, they also stayed soft into the next evening.
The main problem I'm running into, though, is how incredibly sticky the dough is even after kneading.  I have to cover the work surface and my hands in flour, and even then, I can only just barely manage to shape them into spheres.  The recipe I used calls for you to "knead and fold the dough towards the centre of the ball... result[ing] in a smooth outer surface as you form the ball."  This just isn't possible with the converted dough that I've been working with.  It still bakes out well, but they tend to be a little lumpy instead of having a smooth surface.
I followed King Arthur Flour's guidance on how to convert the recipe which emphasizes that you must target a 75% hydration, regardless of what the level of the previous recipe was.
Is there a way I can keep the positive qualities of the tangzhong dough while managing to make it more handle-able?
The recipe I'm using, for the record:
Pre-conversion:



Ingredient
Amount




Flour (AP)
350g


Yeast
2 teaspoons


Baking Powder
2 teaspoons


Sugar
1.5 tablespoon


Cooking Oil
1.5 tablespoon


Water
180g



Post-conversion:
Tanghzong



Ingredient
Amount




Flour (AP)
30g


Water
150g



Dough



Ingredient
Amount




Water
106g


Yeast
2 teaspoons


Sugar
1.5 tablespoon


Flour (AP)
320g


Baking Powder
2 teaspoons


Cooking Oil
1.5 tablespoon




That guide says 75% is ideal because the tangzhong doesn't "count" towards how the dough behaves, but it uses a 60-65% hydration baseline. Your original recipe is closer to 50%, if the 75% tangzhong dough is behaving like significantly higher hydration dough than the original recipe, perhaps 75% is overkill.

You got a comment already that recommends a lower hydration and I think that could help already. Note that you are steaming the dough later which leads to water absorption vs. water loss during conventional baking.
If a high-hydration dough sticks, don’t use lots of flour, that doesn’t help much and can really throw the balance. Instead, use either wet hands or oil (depending on the recipe).
A repeat stretch and fold approach when handling can generate a lot of structure and reduce sticking significantly. There are lots of videos showing different pull/slap methods that start with a gloopy mess and turn it into a cohesive, low-stick ball just by working the dough.
So the tl;dr:
For high hydration dough, work to build dough structure, use wet/oily hands and a bench scraper instead of flour.
For you use case, maybe reconsider the hydration.
